# Prompt to open a txt file with obj.FSO.OpenTextFile

Tags: excel, vba

edit:
so here is my current code with the help from this page - how do i enable it so i can bring in the text file after opening it with the file dialog function?

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lngCount As Long

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Add "Documents", "*.txt", 1
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Show

End With

Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\test\copy.txt", ForReading) 'this is now defunct??

For i = 1 To 5
    objTextFile.ReadLine
Next

strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
Range("A1").Value = strLine

objTextFile.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: `objFSO.OpenTextFile` just opens a text file and nothing more. Do you mean show user the open dialog?

Comment: yes exactly - i need the user to able to select whatever text file they want as each text file will have a randomly different name, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the following page (you are almost correct!) ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226.aspx

You can use this code to ask a user to open a file via an `OpenFileDialog` ...

```
Sub UseFileDialogOpen() 

Dim lngCount As Long 

' Open the file dialog 
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen) 
    .AllowMultiSelect = True 
    .Show 

    ' Display paths of each file selected 
    For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count 
        MsgBox .SelectedItems(lngCount) 
    Next lngCount 

End With 

End Sub
```

Comment: Add a filter that includes text files and make it the first item in the list: `.Filters.Add "Documents", "*.txt", 1`